# firebase prevent child delete not work

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i have this schema

```
"Photo": {
  "$User": {
    "$Photo": {
      ".validate": "auth.uid == $User && ((newData.hasChildren(['created', 'updated', 'image', 'title']) && data.val() == null && newData.val() != null) || data.val() != null && newData.val() != null && newData.child('updated').val() != null)",
      "created": {
        ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && data.val() == null && newData.val() != null && newData.val() == now"
      },
      "updated": {
        ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() == now"
      },
      "image": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && data.val() == null && newData.val() != null"
      },
      "title": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 3"
      },
      "$other": {
        ".validate": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if you see my validate rule

```
 ".validate": "auth.uid == $User && ((newData.hasChildren(['created', 'updated', 'image', 'title']) && data.val() == null && newData.val() != null) || data.val() != null && newData.val() != null && newData.child('updated').val() != null)"
```

i write a permission only for write and for the update but when i delete a node i can delete it. my goal is to prevent the delete. why this? where the error? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you'll want to use a `.write` rule, not a `.validate` rule. [From the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data):

> Additionally, the validate definitions are ignored when data is deleted (that is, when the new value being written is null).